# How can I add a parallax scrolling effect to a standard bootstrap carousel?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, parallax

I have implemented a standard bootstrap carousel as per the example from the W3Schools website (found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp)).

Is there a way I can incorporate a vertical parallax scroll effect (found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp)) to this carousel?  Currently I can only achieve one or the other.

Note: I need the carousel to view images at full screen.

Comment: The easiest way to do it would be check out the .parallax() of materialize css. and add those classes to your carousel.

Comment: @TirthrajBarot this looks promising.  I will investigate further.  Thanks

Comment: Certainly. Even I would be happy to help. @Riples